# Reporting service Function problem

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report page on reporting service.
In Layout tab i have to something that count the rows. I used rowcount(nothing) function to do that but it is insufficent for me. I have to call some function to count rows. How can i write a function and where can i call it from?

Answer (score 2):

Choose Report Properties | Code
Write your function
then in the expression box call it like this

```
=code:  'your function name'
```